# win ultimate 7 network problems

Tags: networking

Here is my problem. The other day I turned on my comp, opened up my network and to my suprise I see "comp #1 Jeff" Then "comp #2RobHP". Now I have no idea who this Jeff person is. I am "RobHP. I can click on his name and a bunch of stuff comes up like "my pics, my docs , my.....and so on" Now I can click on his files and they open right up. So I imagine he can do the same with my files. I never set up any kind of printer or file sharing options. Now when I go to my network settings it has his name in my network but I cannot remove him from it. It won't let me do anything with his name in my network setting execpt view that he is in it.  Somone please tell me how to get this person out of my network. And my Norton firewall keeeps turning off my windows firewall. I know quite a bit about computers and I have never seen anything like this before, considering I would never think about opening up a public network or share any files or printers. . Please help!!

I have a six core processor and 12 gigs of ram and my 10 yr old single core processor and 3 gigs of ram kicks it butt.  HP builds crap!

Comment: This is more appropriate on SuperUser, our site dedicated to questions like this.

Comment: My experience with HP is different. Everything they build runs faster that other hardware with the same specs (same CPU and RAM etc.). They care for IO. And I don't know what this comment has to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you can see his files does not mean he can see yours, go to Control Panel (icon view) > Network and Sharing Center, then click "change advanced sharing settings" on the left side, you can tick "turn off file and printer sharing" to keep anyone from seeing any of your shared folders.

Or if you are on a network you do not trust, you can change your network from "Home" to "Public" this will secure the PC for you as far as networks are concerned. This is the best setting when you are on a network shared by others such as an Apartment, Cafe, Hotel, University or School etc.

You can do this on the main Network and Sharing Center page, click the blue text under your network and change it to Public.
.

[image]

.

By default, Windows 7 only shares "Public" folders, you would have to share other folders on purpose before anyone can access those.

http://Windows.Microsoft.com/en-US/Windows-Vista/Sharing-files-with-the-Public-folder